# How should I fix this mysqli prepare statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

I'm very new to PHP and SQL.  For a school assignment, I need to create a form for users to update customer data.  However, I notice that the update function only updates the customer with the last ID in the data set.  For example, if I have 4 customers in the data set.  I used a drop down box t list the customer id.  When I select id, 1 ~ 3, it says that 0 row is updated.  It only works when I select id, 4.  So I can only update the 4th one.  Can someone take a look at my code and give me some tips on what the issue is and how to fix it?  Thank you!

Here is the "updatecustomer.php" code:

```
    <?php
//Turn on error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
//Connects to the database
$mysqli = new mysql(SERVER_NAME, USERNAME,PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    echo "Connection error " . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}


if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE customer SET fName=?, lName=?, email=?, phone_number=?, address_no=?, address_street1=?, 
    address_street2=?, address_city=?, address_state=?, address_zip=? WHERE customer_id = ?"))){
    echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}

if(!($stmt->bind_param("isssiissssi",$_POST['customer_id'],$_POST['fName'],$_POST['lName'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['phone_number'], $_POST['address_no'],
    $_POST['address_street1'],$_POST['address_street2'],$_POST['address_city'],$_POST['address_state'], $_POST['address_zip']))){
    echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}
if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo "Execute failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
} else {
    echo "Updated " . $stmt->affected_rows . " rows to customer.";
}

?>
```

Here is part of the code in my form:

```
<div>
            <form method="post" action="updatecustomer.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Update Existing Customer</legend>
                    <li>Customer ID:
                        <select name="customer_id">
        <?php
        if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT customer_id, customer_id FROM customer"))){
            echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            echo "Execute failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }
        if(!$stmt->bind_result($customer_id, $customer_id)){
            echo "Bind failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            echo '<option value=" '. $customer_id . ' "> ' . $customer_id . '</option>\n';
        }
        $stmt->close();
        ?>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>First Name: <input type="text" name="fName"> Last Name: <input type="text" name="lName"</li>
                    <li>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"></li>
                    <li>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone_number"></li>
                    <li>Street Number: <input type="text" name="address_no"> Street Line 1: <input type="text" name="address_street1"></li>
                    <li>Street Line 2 (Apt or Unit Number): <input type="text" name="address_street2"></li>
                    <li>City: <input type="text" name="address_city"> State: <input type="text" name="address_state"> Zip: <input type="text" name="address_zip"> </li>
                </fieldset>
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Customer">
                <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Customer">
        </div>
```

Comment: You may want to remove username and password from your question...

Comment: I doubt this is the problem, but it can't do any harm (can it? :-) ) to change your code so that you only get the `customer_id` column once and only bind the `$customer_id` variable once.

Comment: In your `bind_param()` method, your binding the first placeholder to the customer ID, when it is actually the forename. You should bind customer_id last.

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of variables in your `$stmt->bind_param` line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I have made the code neater, and easier to understand, and reordered the customer ID in the `bind_param()` method.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
    UPDATE customer 
    SET fName=?, 
        lName=?, 
        email=?, 
        phone_number=?, 
        address_no=?, 
        address_street1=?, 
        address_street2=?, 
        address_city=?, 
        address_state=?, 
        address_zip=? 
     WHERE customer_id = ?
");

if(!$stmt){
    echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}

$paramBinding = $stmt->bind_param("sssiissssii",
                      $_POST['fName'], 
                      $_POST['lName'], 
                      $_POST['email'], 
                      $_POST['phone_number'], 
                      $_POST['address_no'],
                      $_POST['address_street1'], 
                      $_POST['address_street2'], 
                      $_POST['address_city'], 
                      $_POST['address_state'], 
                      $_POST['address_zip'],
                      $_POST['customer_id']
);

if(!$paramBinding){
    echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}
```

**EDIT**
Then when looping through the options:

```
foreach($stmt->fetch() AS $row){
    echo '<option value="'. $row['customer_id'] . '"> ' . $row['customer_id'] . '</option>\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I changed my code, but now I can only update the customer with ID #1.  Even if I select ID #2 or #3, the changes would only reflect on ID#1.  Can you please give me more tips on what the issue might be?

Comment: I have updated the code, I only made one change, changed `isssiissssi`  to `sssiissssii` in the first parameter of the `bind_param()` method.
Could you try that?

Comment: I tried that, but I can't figure out why all the changes I made are shown in ID#1, not in other ID #s.

Comment: Is it possible that I did something wrong in the drop down box I created for customer ID? Sorry, I think I'm missing something but I don't know what that would be.

Comment: Cant believe I didn't see it before! I have updated my answer with a proper loop to create the options. Try that

Comment: I'm not sure if I added it to the correct place.  I replaced my previous code: "while($stmt->fetch()){
            echo '<option value=" '. $customer_id . ' "> ' . $customer_id . '</option>\n';
        }" with your "foreach" statement.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: Sorry, you need to use `$stmt->fetchAll()` instead of `$stmt->fetch()`. Using `fetch()` only retrieves one result at a time.

Comment: Thank u so much for guiding me on this.  I don't think $stmt->fetchAll() works because when I used it, all the things that I have after the customer table disappeared. Do u think something is not right in the "where" part of my prepare statement? I'm asking because I tried to replace "WHERE customer_id = ?" with "WHERE customer_id = '2'". It allows me to update customer_id #2.  I don't know how I can do that for every id.  If I use customer_id=?, the changes are all shown in id # 1.

Comment: In `updatecustomer.php` on the line where it says `$mysqli = new mysql()`, is it actually `new mysql()` in your code? I think it should be `$mysqli = new mysqli()`

Comment: In my code it is $mysqli= new mysqli(SERVER_NAME, USERNAME,PASSWORD, DATABASE);